# Java. Files and folders. Can't define the type

Tags: java, file, directory

Good Day!

I wrote the method in Java which must search files in folders and do some operations with them.

So the problem is that when I try to check what I have (file or dir) I receive nothing in both cases! But as i can see paths look correct.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the code:

```
public void searchInDir(){

    File inputFile = new File( this.fileName );         
    String[] namesOfFilesDir = inputFile.list();  

    for ( int i = 0; i < namesOfFilesDir.length; i++ )
    {   
        String normalPath = this.getNormalPath(inputFile.getCanonicalPath()); //C:\User -> C:\\User
        // Two separators for correcting path to file
        String pathToCurrentFile = normalPath + File.separator + File.separator + namesOfFilesDir[i];

        File f = new File( pathToCurrentFile, namesOfFilesDir[i] );


        System.out.printf("FileName=%s, Path=[%s]\n", namesOfFilesDir[i], pathToCurrentFile);
        System.out.println(f.isDirectory());//False
        System.out.println(f.isFile());//False too          
        //Some other code           
    }
}
```

---

For example this.fileName consists path to folder ( and this folder consists one folder and 2 files).

I got next:

```
    FileName=Readme.txt, Path=[C:\\workspace\\Grep\\t\\Readme.txt]
    false
    false
    FileName=t2, Path=[C:\\workspace\\Grep\\t\\t2]
    false
    false
    FileName=test.txt, Path=[C:\\workspace\\Grep\\t\\test.txt]
    false
    false
```

Ok. Program says that.

Lets print next code as an example.

```
File f = new File("C:\\workspace\\Grep\\t\\Readme.txt");
System.out.println(f.isFile());
```

Program will print ”True”.

Comment: not sure what you want to accomplish, but why not use File.listFiles(), which gives you proper File objects

Comment: It is part of method which get all files in folder and seek information in them. So it works using recursion. That's why i needed to know kind of file.

But i am only beginner and now i understand that is very bad code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part makes no sense:

```
    String pathToCurrentFile = normalPath + File.separator + File.separator + namesOfFilesDir[i];
    File f = new File( pathToCurrentFile, namesOfFilesDir[i] );
```

Even if we forget about the double separator for the time being, it makes no sense to first construct the file name by adding `namesOfFilesDir[i]`, then construct a File() object using the two-argument constructor which basically adds `namesOfFilesDir[i]` once more. Try printing f.getAbsolutePath() and you'll see what I mean. It should have probably been something like:

```
    File f = new File( normalPath, namesOfFilesDir[i] );
```

Comment: Good point.  ExR, in your first `printf()` debug statement you're printing the value of `pathToCurrentFile`.  But that is NOT the same as the value that your `new File()` constructor is using in the line above.  Do what Sergey says and print the actual path that the `File` object says it is.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the file doesn't exist, so it is neither a file nor a directory. Try printing the output of `f.exists()` as well.

Did you notice the duplicate file separator in your path?

Comment: I wrote 2 File.separator because i should have correct path to file. I want work with them!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. I think you need to revisit your logic - first check if your file is a directory, only if it is a directory that use the `list()` method. In any case, you are not supposed to use two consecutive file separators

Comment: Yes, path wasn't correct. I had 2 name of one file in the path. Thank you!

This mistake have been maiden trough lack of attention.

Answer (score 1):

I think that perhaps your paths are not correct.  Both `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` only return true if the file/directory actually exists.  Have you tried calling `exists()` on the file?  Also, I'm suspicious of what your `getNormalPath()` method is doing - I think it might be mangling the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st System.out.println is missleading!
It would have been better to output the path of `f`.

Anyway, according the output:

> FileName=Readme.txt, Path=[C:\workspace\Grep\t\Readme.txt]

`f` will be `C:\workspace\Grep\t\Readme.txt\Readme.txt`
that is, `namesOfFilesDir[i]` is being appended twice!

It would be easier/better to work just with instances of `File` directly:

```
    File inputFile = new File(this.fileName); 
    File[] files = inputFile.listFiles();
    for (File f : files) {
        System.out.printf("FileName=%s, Parent=[%s]\n", f.getName(), f.getParent());
        System.out.println(f.isDirectory());
        System.out.println(f.isFile());         
        //Some other code
    }
```

Comment: @ExR - added sample with easier solution (IMO)